# Images and Audio files related to Application

Tags: android

I have an Android application which downloads around 100 small images and and 30 audio files to a folder in sdcard. But these images are getting flooded in music and photo gallery of the phone. How to prevent these media contents appearing in other apps of android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a folder where you store images, music, etc...  create blank file named `.nomedia`, and the folder itself name with `.` in the beginning, so it will look like this

```
/sdcard
/sdcard/.myfolder
/sdcard/.myfolder/.nomedia
/sdcard/.myfolder/my_mp3
/sdcard/.myfolder/my_avi
/sdcard/.myfolder/my_mp4
/sdcard/.myfolder/my_jpg
/sdcard/.myfolder/my_png
```

This will hide the folder from common file managers, and prevent scanning it to music library, gallery, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Try to save those into a folder that has a '.' at the beginning of its name.